# game over is not working when player and enemy collide

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

This is my code:

```swift
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
          firstBody = contact.bodyA
          secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
          firstBody = contact.bodyB
          secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & CollisionTypes.enemy.rawValue != 0) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & CollisionTypes.missile.rawValue != 0)) {
          if let enemy = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode,
             let missile = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode {
                missileCollidedWithEnemy(missileNode: missile, enemyNode: enemy)
                
                let gameOverScene = GamerOverScene(size: self.size)
                self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene)
          }
    }
    
    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & CollisionTypes.enemy.rawValue != 0) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & CollisionTypes.player.rawValue != 0)) {
          if let enemy = firstBody.node as? SKSpriteNode,
             let player = secondBody.node as? SKSpriteNode {
                playerCollidedWithEnemy(enemyNode: enemy, playerNode: player)
                
                
          }
    }
    
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == playerCategory) {
         contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
         contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
       } else if (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == playerCategory) {
         contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
         contact.bodyB.node?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
       }
    
       if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory {
         contact.bodyB.node?.removeFromParent()
         contact.bodyB.node?.removeAllActions()
       } else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory {
         contact.bodyA.node?.removeFromParent()
         contact.bodyA.node?.removeAllActions()
       }
```

So my game over does work but only when enemy and missile collide. When I take these lines of code:

```swift
let gameOverScene = GamerOverScene(size: self.size)
                            
self.view?.presentScene(gameOverScene)
```

and place it into the second if statement so game over can show when player and enemy collide, it doesn't work. What's even more confusing is that when I delete the whole first `if` statement and place the line of code into the second one, the same thing happens, the enemy collides with the missile, and game over pops up.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code for your category bit masks and CollisionTypes raw values. You probably have a category bit mask problem if after moving the code to show the Game Over scene to the second if statement the Game Over screen shows when the missile and enemy collide.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting expected behavior. You placed the code to show the Game Over scene when the missile and enemy collide.

Move the code to show the Game Over scene to the if statement where the player and enemy collide. You have to do that to get the scene to show when the player and enemy collide.

If the Game Over scene still only appears when the missile and enemy collide, you most likely have a problem with your category bit masks or the raw values of your collision types.